# How can i control props by the short way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, typeahead

I want to know how can we make this case to be easily ?

I have a custom Typeahead component, this is will make some action of my custom. So i want to control the props of Typeahead by props of TypeaheadCustom component:

In component i call TypeaheadCustom :

```
<TypeaheadCustom propsControler />
```

In TypeaheadCustom component:

```
function TypeaheadCustom({ propsControler ,children, ...otherProps }, ref) {
    if(propsControler=== true) { //make some propsOfTypeahead}
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Typeahead ref={ref} {...otherProps} //propsOfTypeahead>
                    {children}
                </Typeahead>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I want do exactly like this because i want it clean. How can we do that ? Thank you

Comment: Question isn't clear to me. Do you want to create an object and pass that as props to the `Typeahead` component?

Comment: @SinanYaman yes this is exactly  i want for this case. I can use HoC but it unclean and not good for performent

Comment: Is there a reason you don't create the object inside the if check and pass that object just like you did with `{...otherProps}`

Comment: @SinanYaman i meet a special props like inputProps={{readOnly: true,}} and cannot pass it to Typeahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the object inside the condition, and pass that object as props

```
function TypeaheadCustom({ propsControler ,children, ...otherProps }, ref) {
    if(propsControler=== true) { 
        const propsOfTypeahead = {prop1: 1, prop2: 2}
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Typeahead ref={ref} {...otherProps} {...propsOfTypeahead}>
                    {children}
                </Typeahead>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an HoC for this. In the HoC you pass the propsControler. If this is true then return the component otherwise return null. Here is the pseudo code

`

```
function TypeaheadCustom(propsControler, childrenComponent, ref) {
    return propsControler === true ? (<Fragment>
        <Typeahead ref={ref} {...otherProps}> //propsOfTypeahead>
        {<childrenComponent />} // It shall have the props of its own 
            </Typeahead>
    </Fragment>) : null
}
}
```

`